# Extracting some portion of data from text into csv using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have some data in text file as shown below image(it's just a portion of whole data). What is best way to filter out keys?

```
{  u'chan': 5,
   u'cls': 0,
   u'codr': u'4/5',
   u'data': u'ABfxqqqpVVVOAAA='
}
```

Comment: don't link to a picture.. copy and paste example data in your question. Show the code you have tried? Can you read a text file with python? can you extract the dictionary?  Do you know how to write a file with python?

Comment: Look up ast.eval python module.  It will let you take your dictionary as a string, and convert it to a python dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a series of files in the form of what you posted try

```
import csv
filenames=[...]
#open your output file in append mode

with open('output.csv','a+') as out:
    outwriter = csv.writer(out,dialect='excel')

#write your headers
outwriter.writerow(['header1','header2','header3'])

#for every file
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as f:

        #list that holds each row
        csvlines=[]

        #labels you wanna keep
        keep=["u'data'","u'rssi'","u'timestamp'"]
        lines=f.readlines()
        print lines

        #split at first : character
        lines = map(lambda x:x.split(':',1),lines)

        for line in lines:
            if line[0].strip() in keep:

                csvlines.append(line[1].strip())
    #clean from unnecessary characters
            csvlines=map(lambda x:x.replace("u'","").replace("'","").replace(",",""),csvlines)
    #write it to csv and then reset it for the next file.
            if(len(csvlines)==3):
               print "writing"
               print csvlines
               outwriter.writerow(csvlines)
               csvlines=[]
```

Comment: Hi, I have one file containing a lot of those data in same format. How does it work then?

Comment: Reset every 3 appends?

Comment: im getting ValueErorr : invalid mode for 'wa'

Comment: Also if the dile you're reading gets really big you will need a line by line solution instead of readlines()

Comment: I actually tried that too. But it's not writing any data from my file into csv file except headers. I also tried just a set of data, like the above sample.

Comment: What if you create the output.csv beforehand. Still no? I personally tested it with 'wa'.

Comment: still not working. It just wrote Headers in the second row when empty csv file was created

Comment: If you open the textfile do you see u'chan or just chan?

Comment: as I described in the question, it's u'chan

Comment: In my test i ommited the { and} if you clear them out it by replacing them with empty string in replace() should be fine I guess

Comment: see edit,messed up identation but am at work and will fix later. problem was I was ignoring whitespace in front of u'data. tested it now

Comment: for [this](http://pastebin.com/s1dMjySW) I'm getting [this](http://imgur.com/a/Yg1IC). Must not have the exact same formatting in our testfiles.

Comment: That's what I did. Which is strange. The confusion seems to originate from us having different test files. Ie yours have some spaces mine don't etc.

Comment: if you find what went wrong tell me, I'm kind of invested now :P

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It was perfectly fine when I just copied and pasted somehow.. I think it was still indentation issue. Btw, because I removed "u" from original source to filter out the keys, It is also removing u from my base64 so It corrupts my data sets.. If I don't remove u, then it adds u to my base64 so still corrupts. For example, u'ABBAuqVV0aa=', I want to get rid of u in front but not the one inside of data

Comment: There has to be a more elegant way to let it know that this is unicode however a quick solution would be to keep string[1:] You can ask about unicode eval as a different question if you don't have any luck, since it will get more exposure than a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sample data is one record of your data, you can use pandas to subset and export directly to an excel workbook.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({  u'chan': 5,
   u'cls': 0,
   u'codr': u'4/5',
   u'data': u'ABfxqqqpVVVOAAA=',
   u'datr': u'SF10BW125',
   u'freq': u'912.9',
   u'lsnr': u'-8.2',
   u'mhdr': u'8007000002001900',
   u'modu': u'LORA',
   u'opts': u'',
   u'port': 5,
   u'rfch': 1,
   u'rssi': -111,
   u'seqn': 25,
   u'size': 16,
   u'timestamp': u'2016-11-17T09:51:44.406724Z',
   u'tmst': 2477375724L},index=[0])
df = df[['data','chan','timestamp','rssi']]
oName = #Path to desired excel workbook
df.to_excel(oName,'Sheet1')
```

Comment: sample data is just a portion of my text file. I do have multiple of them in it